# Exception message best practices when aligning messages

Tags: c#, .net, exception

We have an exceptions library that is expected to be used over several solutions. We have several custom exception types contained within this library.

The question that has arisen: If we want to align error messages being used in these exceptions, what is the best practise way to accomplish this? For this question, assume that there are 3 or 4 methods across the solutions who want to throw these types of exceptions.

Let's take an example:

```
public class CustomException : Exception
{
    // You can assume that we've covered the other default constructors for exceptions

    public CustomException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }
}
```

The work we want to replace:

```
public void DoWork()
{
    Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

    // ...

    throw new CustomException(string.Format("The guid was: {0}.", id));
}
```

Our current ideas
1/ Define a new constructor that accepts a guid that defines the error message:

```
const string GuidMessageTemplate = "The guid was: {0}.";

public CustomException(Guid id)
    : base(string.format(GuidMessageTemplate, id))
{
}

public void DoWork()
{
    Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

    // ...

    throw new CustomException(id);
}
```

2/ Allow each solution to define exception builder classes/methods that instantiate the consistent exceptions

```
public class ExceptionBuilder()
{
    const string GuidMessageTemplate = "The guid was: {0}.";

    public CustomException BuildCustomException(Guid id)    
    {
        return new CustomException(string.format(GuidMessageTemplate, id));
    }
}

public void DoWork()
{
    Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

    // ...

    var exception = BuildCustomException(id);
    throw exception;
}
```

3/ Another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use first approach. Your exception should encapsulate building error message. Via constructor exception should recieve only context specific information from outside world.If your exception receive full error message via constructor, then client can create an instance of your exception as follows:

```
class InvalidEmailException : Exception
{
   public InvalidEmailException(string message) : base(message)
   {}
}
```

client code:

```
void ClientMethod()
{
   throw new InvalidEmailException(String.Format("GUID {0} is wrong", Guid.NewGuid()));
}
```

But wait, I expect Email in this exception!

Approach with exception builder is over engineering, just use first approach :)

Comment: We took this solution, in particular with the argument of the ability to misuse the exception.